# make headers_install not working as expected

Tags: linux, linux-headers

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed and have installed linux-headers.  I am in the middle of trying to build uClibc-ng and it needs the linux headers.  So when I run the following command from the linux-headers directory I get the following error messages.  What step am I missing?

```
sudo make INSALL_HDR_PATH=/tmp/linux-headers headers_install
  CHK      include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  UPD      include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl'
 needed by 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.
  Stop.
arc/x86/Makefile:216: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

I created a new VM to play with, and its `uname -a` is:

```
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 17:45:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

Some questions:

1. What is the difference between `linux-headers-4.15.0-46` and `linux-headers-4.15.0-46-generic`?
2. On my VM I have 2 sets `linux-header` directories.  One with `4.14.0-29` and one with `4.14.0-46`.  Within each of those sets is 2 directories.  One with and one without `-generic`.  Do I need to maintain both of these sets?
3. Does anyone know of any instructions of what steps need to be performed on a fresh 16.04 Ubuntu image in order to be able to get the linux-headers?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107811/no-rule-to-make-target-arch-x86-entry-syscalls-syscall-32-tbl-needed-by-arch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  I went to GitHub and  get the Linux sources associated with the version of Ubuntu I am running.  I was able to run:

```
make \
  ARCH=<arch-name> O=. -C <path-to-linux-sources> \
  headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=<output-directory>
```

This worked like a charm and did not require having to run in an elevated privileged mode.

Comment: Struggling with ipconfig as part of klibc < 2.0.4-10 . Your response has helped me rebuild klibc from source :-) Have an upvote... I've tried ARCH=x86_64 and it worked. The klibc makefile itself has suggested  INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr/src/klibc/linux . Now I just hope that all I need is a 'cp usr/kinit/ipconfig/static/ipconfig /usr/lib/klibc/bin/' and update-initramfs...

Answer (score 0):

Install the `linux-source` package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

uClibc is fairly old; I recommend installing uClibc-ng instead.

Comment: The first sentence in the question mentions that `linux-headers` is installed.

Comment: It does say that, but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: If you install the appropriate `linux-headers` package on Ubuntu (or any Debian derivative), and run `cd /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, then `make headers_install`, you’ll get the same error as the OP, which leads me to believe the package is installed ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Done. You'd think that it would install the headers in `/usr/include`...

Comment: Yes, linux-source **is** installed.  Also, the related item did not solve my problem.  I did a search for `$(PWD)` and `PWD` and did not find anything relevant to correct.  So, I'm still not able to get the linux headers.

BTW: I am trying to build `uClib-ng`.  I miss-typed it.